# Missing WYSIWYG controls in Trac

Tags: trac, wysiwyg

I'm not sure whether this was the case right after the Trac installation or as the result of some misconfiguration. Below is a screecapture of a wikipage in the edit mode, where the standard WYSIWYG controls (expected to be present just above the text input in the left corner) are missing.

[image]

In an attempt to solve the issue, [TracWysiwygPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracWysiwygPlugin) was installed, but this has not changed the situation.

What could be the reason for missing WYSIWYG controls and how could it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded to Trac 0.12 (was 0.11.7) and everything returned to normal.

Answer (score 1):

See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=645231

For me, it boiled down to jquery.js not being found - manually creating the symlink
resolved the issue.